# Double summing of column in two different tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've got 2 tables.

`'Order details'
OrderID | Quantity | UnitPrice | ProductID
  1002  |    19    |    17     |    824
  1002  |    5     |    15     |    285
  1003  |    7     |    6      |    543
  1004  |    12    |    11     |    205`

`'Orders'
OrderID | CustomerID
  1002  |   224
  1003  |   348
  1005  |   224`

I have to get the id of the customer that has bought maximum of products. As you can see one customer can have not only one OrderID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this should works fine:

```
SELECT TOP 1 customerid
FROM (
SELECT customerid, SUM(od.quantity) AS sum
FROM orders AS O
INNER JOIN order_details AS OD
ON O.orderid = OD.orderid
GROUP BY customerid
ORDER BY sum DESC)
```

Check the tables name

Comment: Unfortunately, it says that there is a syntax error near 1

Comment: SQLite has no `TOP n` and instead uses `LIMIT n`

Answer (score 0):

You can first aggregate, the limit the first record based on the descending order of the `SUM` of `Quantity`:

```
SELECT
    ord.CustomerID,
    SUM(det.Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM
    Orders ord
JOIN
    Order_Details det
    ON  (det.OrderID = ord.OrderID)
ORDER BY
    Quantity DESC
LIMIT 1;
```